# DCT equation in openCV

Tags: opencv, compression, jpeg, scilab, dct

I write JPEG compression in Scilab (equivalent of MATLAB) using function imdct. In this function is used function DCT from openCV and I don't know which equation is used in dct function.

[lenna by imdct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAXtI.png)

[lenna by my_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fnd7.png)

You can see lenna by imdct which is internal function and lenna by my_function is my function in scilab.

I add my code in scilab

```
function vystup = dct_rovnice(vstup)

[M,N] = size(vstup) 

 for u=1:M 
     for v=1:N
        cos_celkem = 0; 

        for m=1:M 
            for n=1:N 
                pom = double(vstup(m,n)); 
                cos_citatel1 = cos(((2*m) * u * %pi)/(2*M));
                cos_citatel2 = cos(((2*n) * v * %pi)/(2*N));
                cos_celkem = cos_celkem + (pom * cos_citatel1 * cos_citatel2);
            end
        end

        c_u = 0;
        c_v = 0;

        if u == 1 then 
            c_u = 1 / sqrt(2);
        else
            c_u = 1;
        end  

        if v == 1 then 
            c_v = 1 / sqrt(2);
        else
            c_v = 1;
        end  

        vystup(u,v) = (2/sqrt(n*m)) * c_u * c_v * cos_celkem; 
    end
end

endfunction

function vystup = dct_prevod(vstup)

Y = vstup(:,:,1); 

Cb = vstup(:,:,2);

Cr = vstup(:,:,3);

[rows,columns]=size(vstup)

vystup = zeros(rows,columns,3)


for y=1:8:rows-7
    for x=1:8:columns-7 
        blok_Y = Y(y:y+7,x:x+7) 
        blok_Cb = Cb(y:y+7,x:x+7) 
        blok_Cr = Cr(y:y+7,x:x+7) 
        blok_dct_Y = dct_rovnice(blok_Y) 
        blok_dct_Cb = dct_rovnice(blok_Cb)  
        blok_dct_Cr = dct_rovnice(blok_Cr) 
        vystup(y:y+7,x:x+7,1)= blok_dct_Y 
        vystup(y:y+7,x:x+7,2)= blok_dct_Cb
        vystup(y:y+7,x:x+7,3)= blok_dct_Cr 
    end
end
vystup = uint8(vystup) 
endfunction
```

You can see equation I used
[EQUATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypYgT.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Please enhance your question following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for us to help you. 

Shortly, please details the following point : 
1. Add a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can directly reproduce your problem.
2. Add the Scilab's version and any toolbox or scripts you used that are not include in the default version of scilab. 
3. Also, you may need to rephrase your question as it is unclear if you need help about programming or partial differential equation

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in the use of different normalization of the resulting coefficients.

The OpenCV library uses this equation for a forward transform (`N=8`, in your case):

[image: forward transform]

The basis `g` is defined as

[image: transform basis]

where

[image: lambda]

(Sorry for the ugly images, but SO does not provide any support for typesetting equations.)

Answer (score 0):

Take care there are several definitions of the dct function (DCT-I, DCT-II, DCT-III and DCT-IV normalized and un-normmalized)

Moreover have you tried the Scilab builtin function dct (from FFTW) which can be applied straightforward to images.